# How to rename multiple files after specific character in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file

I am trying to rename multiple files in C# after specific character.
In my folder I have these files:

- Application.xml.4589.done
- Compatible.xml.8790.done

I want to rename these files like below:

- Application.xml
- Compatible.xml

Basically after .xml I am looking to remove everything.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
       public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Test\");
            FileInfo[] infos = d.GetFiles();
            
            foreach (FileInfo f in infos)
            {
                var extension = f.FullName.Substring(f.FullName.LastIndexOf('.'), f.FullName.Length - 20);
                
                // Need help here
            } 
        }
```

Can anybody help me with that? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-5.0) string by `.` and [`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=net-5.0) the first two elements from the split array and [`Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-5.0) as a string. You will get the desire file name with an extension.

```
//I showed you minimal example to solve your problem, update your code accordingly.
var infos = new List<string>(){"Compatible.xml.8790.done", "Compatible.xml.8790.done"};
foreach (var f in infos)
{
   var newFileName = string.Join(".",  f.Split('.').Take(2)); 
   Console.WriteLine(newFileName);     
}
```

[Try Online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4MYNxq)

Comment: @GlennSing, Does it answer your question?

Comment: It does. Thanks a lot.